# Get url from iframe and update hash in browser url

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, iframe, hash

I've tried a few different things but nothing really worked, basically i need to get the current location/url from the iframe, get the part i want and return it to the hash in the url. how can i do this in javascript?

Answer (score 6):

Select the correct iframe element, pull out the **src** attribute, do your stuff, assign src to window.location.hash

```
var iframe = $('iframe');
var src    = iframe.attr('src');
window.location.hash = src;
```

**EDIT**

If you want to get dynamic location from an `iframe` you have to access `contentWindow` property:

```
var iframe     = $('iframe');
var contentWnd = iframe.attr('contentWindow');
var url = contentWnd.window.location.href;

window.location.hash = url;
```

also interesting reading on getting the contentWindow property:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1592-Getting-IFRAME-Window-And-Then-Document-References-With-contentWindow.htm

Comment: The src is not updated when the user is browsing/going to different pages inside the iframe thus it defeats the purpose.  any other solutions?

Comment: +1 Nice answer, but sadly I think there are still cross domain issues.