# How can i get the hash value from an iframe src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

My iframe is having a url with a hash value when i do iframe.src it just gives me the url without the hash appended to it from the other domain. Can i read the entire url with the hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not likely due to security constraints - I am surprised you can even get the URL

Can you show the code?

Sounds like a duplicate of [How to get iframe contentWindow height in cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3667627/how-to-get-iframe-contentwindow-height-in-cross-domain)

Comment: i am reading the url from the same domain. So its giving me the url. Only thing that i am doing is appending hash to the url from the other domain. The reading is still happening at same domain.

Comment: I think he just means the other URL, i.e. the URL of the iframe.

Comment: @Bart "And iframe content is on different domain "

Comment: Oh, yes, I see now, a comment under another answer. The browser only allows you access to the contents of the iframe if it's on the same domain.

Answer (score 2):

```
var contentWnd = $('iframe').attr('contentWindow');
var hash = contentWnd.window.location.hash;
```

Adaptation of this answer: [Get url from iframe and update hash in browser url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670626/get-url-from-iframe-and-update-hash-in-browser-url)

Comment: thats not possible because accessing the contentWindow when we have a different domain will give security errors.

Comment: i am actually willing to set the height of the iframe. And iframe content is on different domain