# How can i make the parent url automatically update to a unique url when iframe loads particular content?

Tags: url, iframe, parent, tumblr

Okay, i'm extremely new to this sort of thing, so i am probably using incorrect terminology, but i've been trying to find an answer and can't, so i'm asking here!

I have a website made in Tumblr that opens post content inside an iframe.  However, that means my parent url doesn't change according to the iframe content.  Is there a way i can cause the parent url to change according to the post inside the iframe?  On other sites i have just done this manually but it needs to happen automaically here.

Help!  Thanks!

Comment: With jQuery (JavaScript): [SO: Get url from iframe and update hash in browser url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670626/get-url-from-iframe-and-update-hash-in-browser-url#2671003)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve this on a website using a trick to manually modify the address in the URL bar without reloading the page. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) for more information. Unfortunately I am not familiar with how Tumblr works internally so I wouldn't be able to say if you can actually use this. But it seems like the only way to achieve what you want.